How can I cut a hole in this without it becoming non manifold?
I am trying to 3d print a tube. I need to cut out this circle out of my tube but every time I delete the face it is coming up as non manifold. I used the knife project tool to apply the vertices you see in the picture.


Hello and welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the post. It should read like a question, be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the problem so that anyone searching for similar issues is likely to find this. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "this", "help with", "issue" or "question about", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on it. See What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"

can you share the blend file https://blend-exchange.com

If you mean a "traversing" hole, do you try a Boolean modifier ? From two manifolds objects, it should produce a manifold one.

I figured out how to do it apparently I had the objects joined and not joined via the Boolean union modifier separating them and joining them using the Boolean modifier then cutting the hole worked
